# Not able to select previously selected option

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-select

`ng-change` is not getting fired after selection of previously selected option.
Because of which I am not able to handle the same next selection.

```
<select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-change="handleSelection()">                        
    <option value="A" selected>A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
```

I want to show to the user the last selected option and want to handle the same.
But since `ng-model` is not changing on next same option selection `ng-change` is not getting fired.

How to handle this scenario?

Comment: Are you trying to have the user perform multiple selections but from the same select element? As you have said, ng-change will only fire off when a change has occurred. If you are trying to get multiple inputs from a user, you will most likely have to make a new input, or do some cleaning of your old value to "force" the change

Comment: ng-change only fire when the model is changed. if you previously select option `A` and then again try to select option `A` it wont work since the model value  isn't change ng-change will not fire

Comment: Yes im aware of this situation @Joffutt and sachila ranawaka. But i want show the popup message on same next selection. And if i try to clean the old value then user last selection would be gone and don't want that.

Comment: This is default behavior in HTML <select>. If you select an already selected option, it won't fire the onchange again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do without `ng-change` by only checking click count:

1st `click event` raises after each opening `select`

2nd `click event` raises after one item selected

we use `blur event` to clear click count after lost focus

by this way you will get selected item without `change event` and `without selecting new item` :

```
<select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-click="handleSelection()" ng-blur="resetClickCount()">                        
    <option value="A" selected>A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
```

--

```
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.clickCount = 0;

    $scope.handleSelection = function() {
        $scope.clickCount++;
        if ($scope.clickCount==2) {
            alert($scope.selectedOption);
            $scope.clickCount = 0;
        }
    }

    $scope.resetClickCount = function() {
        $scope.clickCount = 0;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'ng-change' if value is changing. In your case you want to handle event when value is not changed, so you may use 'ng-click' to handle the same option selection.

Demo :
http://jsfiddle.net/Despotix/vgw5bxrq/3/

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-click="click()">
          <option value="A" selected>A</option>
          <option value="B" class="option">B</option>
          <option value="C" class="option">C</option>
          <option value="D" class="option">D</option>
   </select>
    {{seletedQueue}}
</div>
```

--

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.seletedQueue = '';
    $scope.click = function(item) {
        $scope.seletedQueue += '->' + $scope.selectedOption;
    }
}
```

You can select twice (or more) the same option:
->B->B->A

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the **selectedOption** value in your controller instead of using '**selected**' attribute.

And to track the previously selected option, you can use a $scope variable and change it at the end of your **handleSelection()** function. **A working demo here** -
[**jsfiddle.net**](https://jsfiddle.net/mahbubmoon/bpzkr05c/)
`

```
$scope.selectedOption = "A";
$scope.lastSelectedOption = "A";
$scope.handleSelection = function(){
console.log("Selected Item: "+$scope.selectedOption);
console.log("Last Selected Item:" + $scope.lastSelectedOption);
console.log("");
$scope.lastSelectedOption = $scope.selectedOption;
}`
```